# How can I verify the username and password without opening the login portal?

Tags: java, authentication

There is an email portal : `email.me.com`. To login into the portal,we need a set of credentials namely `username` and `password`. If the credentials are correct, we are able to login with a success message else a failure message is thrown.

Is there a facility available in Java/or is there a way, I can check if the credentials are correct. I want to check by sending the username and password over the code? Is there any way I can do it?

```
code ------> login server (email.me.com) ---->Auth/Failed
                                                |
                                                |
                                               \ /
                message<-------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't try to implement telepathic insight into web servers mostly for security reasons but mainly because no one could demonstrate such a technology is feasible.

What you can do is use a HTTP client framework like Apache's [HttpComponent](http://hc.apache.org/) to talk to the server as if you were a web browser, fill in the form and submit it.

Or you can contact the site's owners and ask if there is an API which you can use (IMAP, REST).

Note: Your request sounds like "I want to crack accounts on this server". So don't be surprised if you run a few tests and suddenly find your IP address being blocked.